# Accept only letters in constructor using scanner in Java

Tags: java

I guys, i'm trying to create an interactive constructor that take name and surname of the users as input in a scanner...all works, but for design now i want to accept only letters in name and surname, i've tryed with Pattern and Matcher, but the costructor still set number as name or surname (it tell me that is an invalid input but still set it in the User)

```
public User(){
        System.out.println("insert name and surname");
        System.out.println("Name: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a,z - A,Z");
          name = input.nextLine();
          Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
          if(m.matches()) {
              this.setName(name);
          }else{
              System.out.println("invalid input");
          }
          System.out.println("SURNAME:");
          surname= input.nextLine();
          this.setSurname(surname);
          p.matcher(surname);
          System.out.println(Welcome);
          System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }
```

Comment: why would you do all of that in the constructor? Just create a validate method in your class that validates a String, and pass that String to your constructor

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of things going on here that aren't quite right. You are on your own for the stuff other than the regex-issue but consider the other points noted below.

1. the constructor should not be interactive - collect inputs and pass them to the constructor
2. your regex pattern is wrong so it will not match the inputs you actually want
3. you are reading the name into the `name` variable and then testing it - this is why it reports bad input but still stores it
4. you have no error recovery for handling bad input
5. write methods to do thing like build a user or get user input rather than trying to do everything in one place.  Limit responsibilities and it is easier to write, debug, and maintain.

**Regex**

As written, your pattern will probably only match itself because the pattern is not well-defined.  I think what you are trying to do with your regex is `"^[a-zA-Z]+$"`.

- The `^` starts the match at the beginning of the String and the `$` ends the match at the end of the String.  Together it means the input must be an exact match to the pattern (i.e. no extraneous characters).
- The `[a-zA-Z]` defines a character class of alphabet characters.
- The `+` indicates one or more characters of the preceding character class match.

Note that String has a convenience method for pattern-matching so you can do something like

```
String regex = "^[a-zA-Z]+$";
String input = ...
if (input.matches(regex)) { ...
```

Regarding how to create an instance of the User.  ***Write methods to do things*** and let the constructor simply construct the object.

```
// Constructor is simple - just assign parameter arguments to members
public User(String name, String surname) {
  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
}

// a method for constructing a User - get the user input and invoke constructor
public User buildUser(Scanner in) {
  // define the regex in a constant so its not repeated
  String name = promptForString("Enter name", NAME_REGEX, in);
  String surname = promptForString("Enter surname", in);
  return new User(name, surname);
}

// get the input, check against regex, return it if valid
public String promptForString(String prompt, String regex, Scanner in) {
  for (;;) {
    String input = in.readLine();
    if (!input.matches(regex)) {
      System.out.println("Invalid input - try again");
      continue;
    }
    return input;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry for the error, i'm studying java by one month and i'm trying to "stress myself" to learn new thing.....i'm doing that because the exercise ask me to do a cinema menu that when is initialized create a new user that can reserve a sit, or delete his sit and other cinema stuff, and all that has to be made in the console... Thank's a lot for the whole explanation, you advice me to create a method that check the regex ecc and then call this method in the constructor?

Comment: @Antonio-93 my advice is to not put logic in the constructor.  The constructor is for the JVM to build an object that you will use.  Your program should assemble the elements its needs to build that object and then pass those to the constructor.  I'll add an example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd say such complex logic shouldn't be used in a constructor. Use it in our main method or any other dedicated method and construct the object from the processed results:

```
...
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(???);
User user = new User();
String name = scanner.nextLine().trim()
if( p.matcher(name).matches() )
{
  user.setName(name);
}
...
```

Now let's talk about why you code is probably not working correctly and that's because of Regex. The regex expression you use maybe does not what you think. With external third-party tools like [Regexr](https://regexr.com/6ki46) you can see what your expressions do.

In your case you only want to allow character but not numbers. This can be done with the Regex `[A-Za-z]` Now we'd check if the string is a single letter... However names rarely consist of a single character so we've to add a quantifier operator to the regex. Now let's assume a name can range between 0 and infinite letters. In such a case the correct quantifier would be `+` (at least 1) which leads to our final result: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+")`

Code I used for testing:

```
    String val = "";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "^[A-Za-z]+$" );
    try ( Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in ) )
    {
      String input = scanner.nextLine().trim();

      Matcher m = pattern.matcher( input );

      if(m.matches())
        val = input;
    }
    System.out.println("Value: " + val);
```

Comment: The `\\w` character-class will match underscores and digits in addition to letters.  The OP states they want only letters.

Comment: @vsfDawg Thanks for pointing that out! Total confused \w with matching only letters (again). It's like they're always saying... If you want to solve an problem with regex then you've two problems ;)